# Firebase value are not updating on label

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I created some easy calculation system with Firebase values. However if I rate it, the calculations and values are all right but it doesn't update the label.

That is how I get values and do the calculations:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Snuses").queryOrdered(byChild: "Brand")
                     .queryEqual(toValue: brandName)
 ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
      if snapshot.exists(){

           let enumerator = snapshot.children

           while let thisProduct = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {

                  // Chances are you'd have to create a dictionary
                  let thisProductDict = thisProduct.value as! [String:AnyObject]

                  let rating = thisProductDict["rating"] as! Double
                  let ratersCount = thisProductDict["ratersCount"] as! Double

                  let ratingToShow: String = String((ratersCount == 0) ? 0 : rating / ratersCount)

                  let productObject = Product(
                                              rating: rating,
                                              ratersCount: ratersCount, 
                                              ratingToShow: ratingToShow)
                  self.products.append(productObject)
                }

           self.tableView.reloadData()
```

And in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I try to show the ratingToShow on label:

```
cell.ratingLabel.text = products[indexPath.row].ratingToShow
```

And the way I add values are this:

```
let ratingToShow: String = String((products[indexPath.row].ratersCount == 0) ? 0 : products[indexPath.row].rating / products[indexPath.row].ratersCount)
        cell.likeLabel.text = ratingToShow

            self.databaseRef.child("productRatings").child(self.currentUser.generalDetails.uid).child(self.products[indexPath.row].snusProductTitle).child(self.currentUser.generalDetails.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                if snapshot.value as? Bool == true{


                     self.databaseRef.child("productRatings").child(self.currentUser.generalDetails.uid).child(self.products[indexPath.row].snusProductTitle).child("rating").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                        let currentUserRate = snapshot.value
                        cell.ratingView.rating = currentUserRate as! Double
                    })

                }else{

                    cell.ratingView.rating = 0.0
                }
                cell.ratingView.didFinishTouchingCosmos = { rating in
                if snapshot.value as? Bool == true{

                    self.databaseRef.child("productRatings").child(self.currentUser.generalDetails.uid).child(self.products[indexPath.row].snusProductTitle).child("rating").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                        let currentUserRate = snapshot.value as? Double


                        self.databaseRef.child("Snuses").child(self.products[indexPath.row].snusProductTitle).child("rating").runTransactionBlock({
                            (currentData:FIRMutableData!) in
                            var value = currentData.value as? Double

                            if (value == nil) {
                                value = 0.0
                            }
                            currentData.value = value! - currentUserRate!

                            cell.update(rating)
                            return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)

                        })
                        self.databaseRef.child("Snuses").child(self.products[indexPath.row].snusProductTitle).child("rating").runTransactionBlock({
                            (currentData:FIRMutableData!) in
                            var value = currentData.value as? Double

                            if (value == nil) {
                                value = 0.0
                            }
                            currentData.value = value! + rating

                            cell.update(rating)

                            return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)

                        })
                        self.databaseRef.child("productRatings").child(self.currentUser.generalDetails.uid).child(self.products[indexPath.row].snusProductTitle).runTransactionBlock({
                            (currentData:FIRMutableData!) in
                            var value = currentData.value as? Bool

                            if (value == nil) {
                                value = true
                            }
                            currentData.value = [self.currentUser.generalDetails.uid:true]
                            self.databaseRef.child("productRatings").child(self.currentUser.generalDetails.uid).child(self.products[indexPath.row].snusProductTitle).updateChildValues(["rating": rating])
                            return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)

                        })




                    })

                }else{

                    self.databaseRef.child("Snuses").child(self.products[indexPath.row].snusProductTitle).child("ratersCount").runTransactionBlock({
                        (currentData:FIRMutableData!) in
                        var value = currentData.value as? Double

                        if (value == nil) {
                            value = 0.0
                        }
                        currentData.value = value! + 1
                        return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)

                    })

                    self.databaseRef.child("Snuses").child(self.products[indexPath.row].snusProductTitle).child("rating").runTransactionBlock({
                        (currentData:FIRMutableData!) in
                        var value = currentData.value as? Double

                        if (value == nil) {
                            value = 0.0
                        }
                        currentData.value = value! + rating
                        cell.update(rating)

                        return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)

                    })
                    self.databaseRef.child("productRatings").child(self.currentUser.generalDetails.uid).child(self.products[indexPath.row].snusProductTitle).runTransactionBlock({
                        (currentData:FIRMutableData!) in
                        var value = currentData.value as? Bool

                        if (value == nil) {
                            value = true
                        }
                        currentData.value = [self.currentUser.generalDetails.uid:true]
                        self.databaseRef.child("productRatings").child(self.currentUser.generalDetails.uid).child(self.products[indexPath.row].snusProductTitle).updateChildValues(["rating": rating])
                        return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)

                        })
                    }
                }
                })
```

What should I do differently?

Comment: There's not enough information in the question to understand the issue as the problem appears to be more in the code that populates the cell text. However, if you are working with a product object, it would be more like cell.likeLabel.text = productObject.ratingToShow

Comment: I have Product structure also yes.

Comment: Well, the code in your question is conceptually ok, however, you are obviously missing productName, snusNicotine etc to populate the ProductObject with so that code won't work as is. I think we need to take a look at the code that populates the cell. Also, you may want to throw a print statement in here and there to ensure the productObjects in  your products array are not getting altered or omitted.

Comment: You are right, I didn't added those productName etc.. just to make it smaller question, I actually have them. However I tried the printing too.. For example after I rate. It doesn't give me the latest rating.

Comment: Would you mind coming into chat?

Comment: Add a print statement right after let rating = ... and let ratersCount = ... to print those values. Are they valid? If so, then add a print statement to print ratingToShow. Is that valid? If so, the issue does not involve Firebase so you should like at how the Product is being initiated and possibly if the objects in the array are being overwritten. Oh - also, to simplify your code, you could move that calculation to the Products object and just populate the ratingToShow during the init process within the object.

Answer (score 0):

To easily manipulate the incremental values in your User Interface, the general and most basic approach is as such :-

- Update your posts in your Firebase database : using **`runTransactionBlock`**
- Then update your current dataSource for the very same value in your retrieved and stored data in your `Product` struct.

For eg:- Once your user clicks the like button to like it or dislike it, your update the respective action's value in your Backend(Firebase), and also in the `products[indexPath.row].ratingToShow`, and then call ***`self.tableView.reloadData`***. This way you don't have to fetch for the current no of likes from your database every time a user likes or dislikes a post saving your bandwidth.

If your like button has it's **@IBAction** in TableViewCell class then just make a controller reference to **yourTableViewController** and change the datasource:-

```
class yourTabelViewCell : UITableViewCell{

 var tableController : yourTableViewcontroller!
 var indexPathForCell : Int! 


  @IBAction func likeBtnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

     //User likes or dislikes the post....

      self.tableController.products[self.indexPathForCell]. ratingToShow = //Manipulate the value +1 or -1
      self.tableController.yourTableView.reloadData()   // Given yourTableView is the custom tableView you have implemented in your viewController
    }
   }
```

For getting the ***indexPathForCell***, just initialise the value in your **`cellForRowAt indexPath : _`**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourTabelViewCell_identifier", for: indexPath) as! yourTabelViewCell

    cell.likeLabel.text = products[indexPath.row].ratingToShow
    cell.indexPathForCell = indexPath.row
    return cell
      }
```

And don't worry about the user loosing network connection while liking or disliking the post, **`runTransactionBlock`**'s are loaded in the local cache so once your user regains network connection, those commands will be executed

Comment: The problem  is, it is not liking, it is rating. I gotta calculate it. So I can't cosmetically add the value. Liking system is easy.

Comment: by rating you mean average? Just put the algorithm together,  once your user rates, in ratersCount, increment those to +1 and rating to whatever rate the user rates (in your datasource and your backend simultaneously) and calculate and present it in the UI you only need to make one call to your backend and the changes reflect instantaneously, its only maths, liking and rating are potentially the same give or take few mathematical manipulations.

Comment: I have the algorithm for that. If you look at my given code then you should see it.

Comment: That after rating the rating stays same on label.

Comment: Once you update your value you need to change the value in your dataSource too , by passing the *rating* , *ratersCount* just same as *indexPathForCell* to your tableViewCell class calculate it there in the like button or rate button **@IBAction**  update the *ratingToShow* and then reload the tableView